# How to Avoid Looping in Webbroser Navigate Function

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, webbrowser-control

I am writing a C# Winforms program that uses the WebBrowser control. In my program I use the Navigate function whenever I click on a link in my webrowser page so I can create some text and assign it to
WebBrowser.DocumentText.  This works fine.  However, the program also can execute a WebBrowser.Navigate(url) function which creates a program loop as it keeps coming back through the OnNavigate function as shown below:

```cs
private void OnNavigate(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    string url = e.Url.ToString().Replace("about:", "");
    ............
}
```

So the problem is that if I have a OnNavigate Event or function in my program and I also execute a WebBrowser.Navigate(url) function the program will keep looping through the OnNavigate function shown above when executing the WebBroswer.Navigate function.  If I remove the OnNavigate Event from my program then the WebBrowser.Navigate(url) function will not loop and will display the appropriate page.

Does anyone know why this happening or how I can keep the WebBrowser.Navigate function from looping through OnNavigate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the onNavigate event to a handler, you can saying, whenever I navigate, run this function.

The only reason I can see a looping happening is that you are calling another navigate in the event handler. So check that a navigate call doesn't exist in the call stack either in the event handler or a function called by the event handler.

If that's the issue and the intent of the handler is to do something to the url before navigating, you are probably using the wrong event and need a beforeNavigate event or a Navigating event which allows you to cancel the navigation or modify the url before navigation.

In any case, if you can't find where you are looping, what you can do is to set a variable for the whole form e.g.

```
bool navigating=false;
```

When you want to navigate, you do:

```
navigating=true;
webbrowser.navigate(aurl);
navigating=false;
```

In the event handler, you do

```
private void OnNavigate(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
  if (navigating)
    return;
  string url = e.Url.ToString().Replace("about:", "");
  ............
}
```

Comment: I have tried to put in code that would do an immediate return if I was navigating but it still kept looping.  Also, I do have some Webbrower.Navigate instructions in the OnNavigate event.  I will delete those instructions  and try it again and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I removed the Webbrowser.Navigate function from my OnNavigate Event and now my navigating is not looping anymore.  Many thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Cool. I do wonder why it was there in the first place. There was something it was supposed to do after every navigate. Perhaps it's just a matter of moving all that stuff out of the onnavigate handler and putting it in the same function where the webbrowser1.navigate is first called. In any case, glad you figured it out.